# How to implement a content security policy for an iframe in a chrome extension popup?

Tags: express, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Currently I have a chrome extension that on click opens a popup with an iframe in it.

The iframe currently references a local deployment thru http://localhost:5000. I've now set a content security policy in my apps index.js file (done thru express) via this line

```
res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "frame-ancestors 'self' http://localhost:*/*");
```

ive also set the content-security-policy of the manifest.json like so

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self' chrome-extension://randomletters/ http://localhost:5000/*; frame-src 'self' http://localhost:5000/*; child-src 'self' http://localhost:5000/*;",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-modals; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; child-src 'self';frame-ancestors 'self' http://localhost:5000/*;"
  }
```

however I still run into this error when trying to load the modal

> Refused to frame 'chrome-extension://randomletters/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' chrome-extension://randomletters/ http://localhost:5000/*"

is there a layer of policy im missing? not sure why the chrome extension won't load when i've already added the url it says thats not allowed into the CSP...

this is how it is iframed in html (extension-content.html)

```
  <iframe id="myIframe" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.heroku.app.com"></iframe>
```

and extension-content.js
opens the iframe like this

```
  const message = {
    data: {
      screenX: window.screenX,
      screenY: window.screenY,
    },
    message: 'WINDOW_PARAMS'
  };
  const iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
}
```

to get to that logic,
in background.js, i have this logic

```
  closeIframesInTabs(() => {});
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    // tabs is an array of all currently open tabs, but only the active tab is at index 0
    const activeTab = tabs[0];
    if (!tabsWithIframes.hasOwnProperty(activeTab.id) && !activeTab.url.includes('chrome://')) {
      // Inject the content script
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
        files: ["iframe-content/extension-side-panel.js"],
      }, () => {
        // Mark this tab as injected
        openExtension(activeTab);
      });
    } else {
      openExtension(activeTab);
    }
  });
});
```

where extension-side-panel is the parent file for two possible iframes, one of which is extension-content

Comment: You need to add `chrome-extension://randomletters` to frame-ancestors in your localhost app's CSP header. You don't need frame-ancestors in `extension_pages`.

Comment: so i added chrome-extension://randomletters into my apps CSP header, and now the extension popup modal loads the frame if i am on chrome-extension://randomletters when clicking it. 
i deployed the app from localhost to heroku.app.com
however if i i go to like w2schools.com or wikipedia , it still gives me the error:

Refused to frame 'https://heroku.app.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' *.force.com chrome-extension://randomletters/ https://heroku.app.com/".

is there something in the manifest i am missing?

Comment: or is iframe security not possible if i am trying to make the iframe openable from the extension from any web page?

Comment: Assuming the popup is the `action` popup, it's a separate page that doesn't depend on what's in the tab. Show the code for the iframe and the popup so that we can see the relation of all entities.

Comment: @wOxxOm updated my description to include relevant code, let me know if you need more context

Comment: You can't use frame-ancestors in this case because it applies to all ancestors upwards. If you want to ensure it's only inside your chrome extension your app can check `location.ancestorOrigins[0]` but it's not available in Firefox. For a compatible solution you can use parent.postMessage('ping', 'chrome-extension://.....')